# Types Indexing working unexpectedly and throwing unaccounted for errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-types, typescript-class

This following code just seems bizarre to me...

```
export class Collection {
    private data: {[k: string]: any} = {};
    constructor () {
        // WORKS AS EXPECTED
        this.data["hello"] = "hello";

        // UNEXPECTEDLY WORKS
        this.data[2] = 2;
    }
}
export class Collection2 {
    private data: {[k: symbol]: any} = {};
    constructor () {
        // DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED
        this.data["hello"] = "hello";

        // UNEXPECTEDLY DOESN'T WORK
        this.data[Symbol.iterator] = function () {}
    }
}
```

If I set the index signature to `string`, only strings should be able to index it right? Same with symbol. However, numbers are able to index `[k: string]` and I get an error saying that `symbol` can't be used as an index signature.

Comment: Regarding using symbol as index type: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863

Comment: You can't use `symbol` in an index signature (not [yet](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797) anyway), so `{[k: symbol]: any}` is invalid TypeScript.  You can use specific symbol-valued properties as keys in a type, though, as in `private data: { [Symbol.iterator]?: any } = {};`.  What's your use case?

Comment: Well, thank you for that answer! But that still doesn't answer how `this.data[2] = 2;` works when I have already done `private data: {[k: string]: any} = {};`. As for my use case, it's is simply to build a collection class to store data for a project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's bizarre to me too, but it's expected behavior.  Per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures):

> An index signature parameter type must be ‘string’ or ‘number’. If you have a type with a string index signature, keyof T will be string | number (and not just string, since in JavaScript you can access an object property either by using strings (object["42"]) or numbers (object[42]))